# Externalizing Properties file for local Maven repo jar

Tags: java, maven, executable-jar, properties-file

I have a maven project (which has Properties file) which I packaged as a jar and added to my applicaiton local repo. Is it possible to externalize the property file which I'm using in packaged jar file? I looked up in google and SO but couldnt find any relevant solution. Any pointers would be helpful.

Comment: yes. do not embed your properties in the jar. put it on your classpath, and load it using getClass().getResource(). Or put it anywhere and load it as a standard java.io.File. Globally speaking, it is always a bad idea to put configuration inside a jar.

Comment: @S.Piller The packaged jar file will be in Maven Dependencies of the application. How do I put the properties file in classpath?

Comment: the contract of your jar file should not be "declare a property file somewhere and I will load it" but rather "give me some values I don't care from where it comes". This way, your jar file only need values, and your consumer (the main jar) can do whatever he want to provides those values - for example, load them from a property file. treat a property file as an implementation details (it could be replaced with a jndi lookup or a db query...)

Comment: Ok got your point. Is there a way out with my current setup?

Comment: your current setup, we even don't know how you are loading that file... Global answer is: if you are relying on the classpath (getClass().getResource() and other), just put your file somewhere in the classpath or alter your classpath to include your location (see argument -cp of the java command). Else load your file from a fully qualified path or whatever. Give us some code to get better answers.